# PYTHON ¿Por qué HDBSCAN considera todos los datos como ruido?

Tags: python, cluster

[Editado] En python, HDBSCAN considera todos mis datos como ruido, es decir, tras hacer el HDBSCAN.fit(data) labels_ es un array lleno de "-1". ¿Alguna idea de por que ocurre esto? data tiene la forma de un array de series tamaño 16

```
col=['Historico','Hora','Grupo']
data=data[col]
data=data.dropna(axis=0)
data_final=data.groupby('Grupo')
for index,grupo in data_final:
    if(len(grupo['Historico'])==16):
        data_agrupada.append(grupo['Historico'])
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN()
clusterer.fit(data)
s,_nClusters=np.unique(clusterer.labels_,return_counts=True)
clusters=[]
for i in range(_nClusters):
    clusters.append([])
for i,j in zip(clusterer.labels_,data):
    clusters[i].append(j)
datos=getInfo(clusters)
```

Comment: Hola Miguel, por favor, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía __[mcve]__?

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido resolver el problema incializando el clusterer de la siguiente manera:

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=2)
```

Ya que tengo muy pocos datos y no se conseguía que ningun cluster alcanzará el numero minimo de valores que se requería por defecto